# How to highlight certain symbols only inside math environment?

Tags: latex, auctex, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

I'd like to have certain math symbols highlighted. I checked AUCTeX manual but there does not seem to be a built-in way to do that. They are not folded forms or anything, but the real glyphs, which I use with xelatex. For example, I'd like to highlight the unicode characters =,+,×,⊆, ⊂, ∩, ↦, →,≥,≤,≅,≃,∀,∃,∈, etc. But I'd like that to happen only inside a math, not if the characters appear in text mode.

[This section](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#User_002ddefined-keyword-classes) of AUCTeX's manual talks only about adding custom keywords started with a backslash.

Comment: Please make clear what kind of highlighting you want/need. You added tag `syntax-highlighting` - is that what you need? Do you want font-lock highlighting, or do you just want to highlight those chars?

Comment: @Drew I'd like syntax hilighting.

Comment: Then define `font-lock-keywords` (via `font-lock-add-keywords` or `font-lock-defaults`), to specify those chars within a "math" context (only). See the Elisp manual, node [Font Lock Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-Lock-Mode.html) and its subnodes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @Tera -- although Drew:s suggestion is correct, learning to write complex font-lock rules is a major undertaking. I suggest that you look at similar packages and try to understand how they are designed. I've written several packages and tools, e.g. https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-doxygen and https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio

Comment: @Lindydancer It does seem to require an effort. Thank you for your suggestions. I'll have a look at your packages too.